# how do I find out if a Java field has the transient modifier?

Tags: java, reflection, transient

In the Java reflection world -

how do we find out if a Field object has the transient modifier?

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/reflect/member/fieldModifiers.html

the documentation is not helping.

Answer (score 59, accepted):

```java
import java.lang.reflect.Field;
import java.lang.reflect.Modifier;

Field field = YourClass.class.getField("fieldName");
boolean isTransient = Modifier.isTransient(field.getModifiers());
```

For more details see [Class Modifier](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/reflect/Modifier.html)